# Prove $rs=sr^{-1}$ in ${\rm Dih}(2n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

> Let $r$ and $s$ be the rotation and reflection symmetries respectively in ${\rm Dih}(2n)$, the dihedral group of order $2n$. Show that $rs=sr^{-1}$.

I also need to show by induction that $r^js=sr^{-j}$ but I think that will follow easily.

Comment: What have you done? Have you tried doing it directly, and verifying that $rs=sr^{-1}$? The induction step is also immediate (assuming base case).

Comment: Also I haven't used this site much and am having trouble formatting the title so help with that would be appreciated

Comment: The following hint may be hard to digest, so I try it as a comment. Assume that $r$ is rotation by angle $\phi$. Can you convince yourself about the fact that $s^{-1}rs$ is then rotation by angle $-\phi$? This is because you first take a mirror image, then rotate that, and reflect it back. Effectively you will be rotating the mirror image which amounts to rotating the original in the opposite direction.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Should I delete my answer regarding to anon's comment? Thanks.

Comment: @BabakS. I don't think so! Different readers of this question will want to see different answers. It is unlikely that your answer will help someone on a first course in groups, but I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I don't know if this proof works so I'm posting it as a comment: $rs$ must have order 2, if it had any other order $Dih(2n)$ will have more elements than $2n$. From there you have $rs=(rs)^{-1}$ and thus $rs=s^{-1}r^{-1}$

Answer (score 5):

You can see $\text{Dih}(2n)$ as a subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$. Thus $r= \left( \begin{matrix} \cos(\pi/n) & -\sin(\pi/n) \\ \sin(\pi/n) & \cos(\pi/n) \end{matrix} \right)$ and $s= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then $srs= \left( \begin{matrix} \cos(\pi/n) & \sin(\pi/n) \\ -\sin(\pi/n) & \cos(\pi/n) \end{matrix} \right)=r^{-1}$.

Another possibility is to notice that $\det(srs)=\det(r)=1$ and $\text{Tr}(srs)=\text{Tr}(r)=2\cos(\pi/n)$. Therefore, $srs$ is a rotation of angle $\pm \pi/n$. If $srs=r$, then $r$ and $s$ commute and you deduce that $\text{Dih}(2n)$ is itself abelian, which is false. So $srs$ is a rotation of angle $-\pi/n$, ie. $srs=r^{-1}$.

Comment: $\Large{+1}$. Your way made me favorite the question.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  First you want to show that if $r$ is a rotation and $s$ is a reflection, then $rs$ must be a reflection.  What is the square of any reflection?  What is the inverse of any reflection?

Comment: +1 for the nice idea, but it is uncertain, whether a student encountering groups for the first time will be able to use the hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find it in many Group theory book as a Theorem or as an exercise. Now, let $G_1,G_2$ are two groups and let $\phi:G_2\to Aut(G_1),~~\phi(b)=\phi_b$ (I assume you know what is $\phi_b$). We can prove that $G_1\times G_2$ with the following operation:

$$(a,b)(a',b')=(a\phi_b(a'),bb')$$

is a new group and you know that it is $G_1\times_{\phi} G_2$ called the semi-direct product of $G_1$ by $G_2$. In fact, assuming that $\phi_b$  where $b\in G_2$ is essential here. Now, let $G_1=\mathbb Z_n=\langle a\rangle$ and $G_2=\mathbb Z_2=\langle b\rangle$. Consider: $$\phi:G_2\to Aut(G_1)\\\\ \phi(b)=\phi_b,~~\phi(1)=\phi_1=id_{\mathbb Z_n}$$ $\phi$ is a group homomorphism and we denote $\mathbb Z_n\times_{\phi}\mathbb Z_2$ as $D_{2n}$. Here, you can find out why that relation is regarded. Just consider the way  $\phi$ acts.

Comment: The definition of dihedral groups as semidirect products seems too advanced for the OP.

Comment: @anon: Unfortunately, I couldn't understand in what level I should talk to the OP. But I think, missed Arturo pointed good points here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/39724/8581.

Comment: Well done, Babak!+1

Comment: @BabakS.:$\Large{+❶}{☻}{✓}$

Comment: @flashdesign2550: Na :) Didam chizi umade baram amma mese inke paak shode. In bud ke porsidam.