# The elements of the dihedral group $D_{24}$ and their orders.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

If I know that one presentation for the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is

$$D_{2n} = \langle r,s\mid r^n = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1}\rangle$$

And also, I know that $$D_{2n} = \{1,r,r^2, \dots , r^{n-1},s,sr,sr^2, \dots , sr^{n-1}\}.$$

How can I find the order of each element?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39631/computing-the-order-of-elements-in-dihedral-groups/39634).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The answer is obvious for elements of the form $r^k$.  For elements of the form $sr^k$, you can repeatedly use the relationship $rs=sr^{-1}$ to "walk" the interior $s$ all the way to the left.  In particular, you can prove by induction a formula for $(sr^k)^m$.

Comment: How the orders are obvious for the elements of the form $r^k,$ could you explain please?

Comment: Just use that $(r^k)^m=r^{km}$.

Comment: For the remaining part of your answer I will work it and let you know if my problem was solved or not. Thank you by the way, cheers

Comment: what is your $m$ ?

Comment: It's arbitrary.  For any specific $k$, find the smallest $m$ such that $r^{km}=1$.  That will be a formula involving $\gcd(k, n)$.